При обновлении страницы графики не переведываются
У меня информация в object заносится при помощи нажатии на кнопку, а после обновления страницы, оно у меня становится пустой строкой и соотвественно графики не рендарятся. Вот мой код reduxtoolkit:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  base: "",
};

const objectSlice = createSlice({
  name: "object",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    findObject(state, action) {
      state.base = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { findObject } = objectSlice.actions;

export default objectSlice.reducer;

Вот мой код компонента:
import "./FullInfo.scss";
import full from "../../images/fullscreen.svg";
import CardCount from "../CardCount";
import CardDevice from "../CardDevice";
import CardDoughnut from "../CardDoughhnut";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { UseSelector, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const FullInfo = () => {
  const object = useSelector((state) => state.object.base);
  console.log(object);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const DATA_URL = `https://31.44.94.234:63100/${object}/devstat.sql`;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (object) {
      axios
        .get(DATA_URL)
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }, [object]);

  return (
    <div className="root">
      <div className="root-title">
        <h1>Текущее техническое состояние</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="first-row">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-title">
            Количество устройств по объектам
            <img src={full} alt="Во весь экран" />
          </div>
          <div className="card-information" style={{ width: 600 }}>
            <CardCount data={data} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-title" style={{ marginLeft: -70 }}>
            Количество устройств по видам наблюдений
            <img style={{ marginLeft: 35 }} src={full} alt="Во весь экран" />
          </div>
          <div className="card-information" style={{ width: 600 }}>
            <CardDevice data={data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="second-row">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-title" style={{ marginLeft: -30 }}>
            Количество устройств в каждом состоянии
            <img src={full} alt="Во весь экран" />
          </div>
          <div
            className="card-information"
            style={{ width: 400, marginTop: -40, marginLeft: 130 }}
          >
            <CardDoughnut data={data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FullInfo;

В адресную строку вшивается имя бд, из которой я беру информацию, но при обновлении страницы получается так, что ни на какую кнопку я не нажимал, в object пустая строка, и запрос не может выполниться

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

а после обновления страницы, оно у меня становится пустой строкой так у тебя так в коде и написано... Не хочешь "пустую строку" - записывай изменения в тот же localStorage, а при "обновлении страницы" читай.

Вот похожий на ваш вопрос
